# check occurence of a timestamp in a column of timestamps

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I have a column with timestamps formatted like this printing one row it looks like this for example:

```
"2022-09-21 02:02:03 UTC"
```

There are many rows that have the same timestamp, but I want another column with the first timestamp after a specific times based on a vector that looks like this:

```
start_1 <- strptime("07:15:00, format= "%H:%M:%S") 
start_2 <- strptime("09:15:00, format= "%H:%M:%S")
```

Based on my start_1 timestamp I want to check in my df below which is the first timestamp after start_1 and mark that one in another column called start_datetime.

I only want to mark the first timestamp after the start in my dataset, this is crucial for what I am trying to do, since many of the rows have exactly the same timestamp.

| Datetime | start_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-21 07:02:03 | NA |
| 2022-09-21 07:02:03 | NA |
| 2022-09-21 07:14:03 | NA |
| 2022-09-21 07:16:03 | 07:16 |
| 2022-09-21 07:16:03 | NA |
| 2022-09-21 09:19:03 | 09:19 |

I've explored multiple options, but so far I've been struggling to find a solution.

Comment: Please give actual working code. Here your `strptime` calls are both missing closing-parens.

Comment: Are you expecting that `start_1` (and 2) is just a time component? Base R doesn't do that, the `strptime` calls return a _full_ timestamp that includes the date. What class is your `Datetime` column? (If it is not `character`, then it is often easier if you (also) provide sample data using `dput(.)`. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is a "per day" thing, meaning that your `start_1` and `start_2` just reflect time-of-day (which means `strptime` is not doing what you want).

If your `Datetime` column is class `character`, then we can make some assumptions about lexicographic sorting and do something like this:

```r
start_1 <- "07:15:00"; start_2 <- "09:15:00"
library(dplyr)
# library(purrr) # map_dfc
quux %>%
  mutate(
    Date = substring(Datetime, 1, 10),
    purrr::map_dfc(list(s1 = start_1, s2 = start_2),
                   ~ if_else(substring(Datetime, nchar(Datetime) - 7, nchar(Datetime)) > .,
                             ., .[NA]))
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(s1, s2), ~ replace(., duplicated(.), NA)), 
    start_datetime = coalesce(s1, s2)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Date, -s1, -s2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Datetime            start_datetime
#   <chr>               <chr>         
# 1 2022-09-21 07:02:03 NA            
# 2 2022-09-21 07:02:03 NA            
# 3 2022-09-21 07:14:03 NA            
# 4 2022-09-21 07:16:03 07:15:00      
# 5 2022-09-21 07:16:03 NA            
# 6 2022-09-21 09:19:03 09:15:00
```

In fact, we can generalize this to any number of `starts`.

```r
fun <- function(time, starts) {
  tmp <- which(
    apply(outer(time, starts, `>`), 2, function(z) replace(z, c(FALSE, z[-length(z)]), FALSE)),
    arr.ind = TRUE)
  replace(time[NA], tmp[,"row"], starts[tmp[,"col"]])
}
starts <- c("07:15:00", "09:15:00")

quux %>%
  mutate(
    Date = substring(Datetime, 1, 10),
    Time = substring(Datetime, 12, 19)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(start_datetime = fun(Time, starts)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Date, -Time)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Datetime            start_datetime
#   <chr>               <chr>         
# 1 2022-09-21 07:02:03 NA            
# 2 2022-09-21 07:02:03 NA            
# 3 2022-09-21 07:14:03 NA            
# 4 2022-09-21 07:16:03 07:15:00      
# 5 2022-09-21 07:16:03 NA            
# 6 2022-09-21 09:19:03 09:15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. To use a variable from the *Global Environment* *"start_1"* and *"start_2"* try `.env` or `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

start_1 <- hms("07:15:00")
start_2 <- hms("09:15:00")

df %>% 
  mutate(time = hms(sapply(strsplit(Datetime, " "), "[", 2)), 
         d1 = time > .env$start_1, 
         d2 = time > .env$start_2, 
         start_datetime = 
           case_when(lag(d1) != d1 ~ paste0(hour(time), ":", minute(time)), 
             lag(d2) != d2 ~ paste0(hour(time), ":", minute(time)))) %>% 
  select(Datetime, start_datetime)
             Datetime start_datetime
1 2022-09-21 07:02:03           <NA>
2 2022-09-21 07:02:03           <NA>
3 2022-09-21 07:14:03           <NA>
4 2022-09-21 07:16:03           7:16
5 2022-09-21 07:16:03           <NA>
6 2022-09-21 09:19:03           9:19
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Datetime = c("2022-09-21 07:02:03", "2022-09-21 07:02:03",
"2022-09-21 07:14:03", "2022-09-21 07:16:03", "2022-09-21 07:16:03",
"2022-09-21 09:19:03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```